# Chrome: trigger click event with jQuery (it works with Firefox)

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome, canvas

The idea is: you have a file field, which is hidden, and an image. You use the image to show the select file dialog. Then I display the image in the canvas.

```
<input id="ytfile-select" type="hidden" value="" name="Foto[image]" />
<input style="display:none" id="file-select" accept="image/*" 
name="Foto[image]" type="file" />
<img id="upload-image" src="/images/design/upload-image.png" 
alt="upload-image-button" />        
<canvas id="canvas">  
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support the &lt;canvas&gt; element.  
</canvas>  

$('#upload-image').click(function(){
  $('#file-select').click();
});


$('#file-select').bind('change',function(){
  var fileList = this.files;  
  var img = document.createElement("img");  
  img.classList.add("obj");  
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[0]);  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
});
```

On Firefox 10, `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);` *only works when* I have the Firebug debugger nad breakpoint on that line. Without the breakpoint, it doesn't work. I checked it on another clean profile.

On Chrome, `$('#file-select').click();` doesn't open the file dialog.

---

**Edit**: this question has been already answered. However, I have no idea what the issue with Firefox is. Any ideas?

I used these websites to create this code:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications
- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

**Edit 2**:
I resolved the issue with the Firefox by doing this:
Behind the line `var fileList = this.files;`, I put:

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
    $('#display').append('<img src ="' + event.target.result + '">');
};
reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
```

Comment: Stating the obvious, but is your script inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: Can't soft click by <input type="file"/> by security reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will trigger the `click` event:

`$('#file-select').trigger("click");`

**Example:**

```
<input type="file" id="filesel" name="file" style="position:absolute;left:-999px;top:-999px" />
<a onclick="$('​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​#filesel').trigger('click');" href="#">click to open</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t7P3v/

**Update:**

Indeed, if the `input type="file"` is `display:none` it will not pop up. Still you can make it invisible to the user by some CSS: `position:absolute; top:-999px; left:-999px`

Comment: It's working for me using the latest version of Chrome. The file dialog opens.

Comment: Your example is also working for me. I used .trigger('click'); in my code before and it didn't  success.

Comment: Your code will not run if you make the input type not being displayed:<input type="file" id="filesel" name="file" style="display:none;"/><br />

Comment: `.trigger("click")` is just more verbose way of saying `.click()`

Comment: So update your code to have the trigger call and let us see why isn't it working.

Comment: it will not run with display:none, but it will run with: visibility:hidden :) Still got the problem with the firefox.

Comment: @Jakub so then make it disappear from the screen! I updated the JSFiddle demo. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

try [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/YKp9x/13/) on jsfiddle. I cant remember where I copy this plugin.

plugin code

```
jQuery.fn.file = function(chooseHandler) {
    return this.each(function() {

        var element = $(this),
            element_name = element.attr('data-name'),
            element_id = element.attr('data-id');

        // check name of radio-group
        if (element_name == undefined) {
            alert('Error: fileInput must have name!');
        }

        var holder = $('<div></div>').appendTo(element).css({
            position:'absolute',
            overflow:'hidden',
            '-moz-opacity':'0',
            filter:'alpha(opacity: 0)',
            opacity:'0',
            zoom:'1',
            width:element.outerWidth()+'px',
            height:element.outerHeight()+'px',
            'z-index':1
        });

        var _input;

        var addInput = function() {
            _input = holder.html('<input name="' + element_name + '" type="file" style="border:none; position:absolute;cursor:pointer;">').find('input');

            if (element_id != undefined) {
                _input.attr('id', element_id);
            }

            if (chooseHandler) {
                _input.change(chooseHandler);
            }
          };

        var position = function(e) {
            holder.offset(element.offset());

            if (e) {
                _input.offset({left:e.pageX-_input.outerWidth()+25, top:e.pageY-10});
            }
        };

        addInput();

        element.mouseover(position);
        element.mousemove(position);
        position();        
    });
};
```

usage

```
<div id="my-select" data-name="name-of-autogenerated-input-element" class="some custom button style"></div>


...
$("#my-select").file();
```

Comment: Thanks. What does this code do? Does it only show the file dialog, or also displays the image? I tried it, but the image haven't been displayed on firefox and chrome.

Comment: hm.. this code show image and hided file input under image... try set another image url

Comment: I see the image, when I click on it, I get the file dialog.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen the issue about FF bug.. I dont know why he behaves

Comment: I resolved the issue with firefox. My post has been updated. I used this website to resolve it: http://html5demos.com/file-api